# How to save Magento 2 invoice PDF file with order ID instead of date?

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf, filesystem

When I print any invoice in Magento 2 the pdf save according to the current date I am saving it as for example

> invoice2023-05-10_05-58-26.pdf

Instead, I wanted to save this pdf with order id like

> invoice-100022920.pdf

Can anyone help me out with how can I come out with the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to override this file:**

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Invoice/AbstractInvoice/PrintAction.php
```

- In **VendorName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml** file, add the following code to Register the overridden controller:
- In **VendorName/ModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/Invoice/AbstractInvoice/PrintAction.php** file, extend the
  **Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice\AbstractInvoice\PrintAction** class and override the **execute()** method.

---

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice\AbstractInvoice;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class PrintAction extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice\AbstractInvoice\PrintAction
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $invoiceId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id');
        if ($invoiceId) {
            $invoice = $this->_objectManager->create(
                \Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface::class
            )->get($invoiceId);
            if ($invoice) {
                $pdf = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice::class)->getPdf([$invoice]);
                $date = $this->_objectManager->get(
                    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime::class
                )->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');
                $fileContent = ['type' => 'string', 'value' => $pdf->render(), 'rm' => true];

                $orderIncrementalId = $invoice->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
                return $this->_fileFactory->create(
                              'invoice-' . $orderIncrementalId . '.pdf',
                              $fileContent,
                              DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
                              'application/pdf'
                );
            }
        } else {
            return $this->resultForwardFactory->create()->forward('noroute');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much @Ronak Perfectly worked.

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding...:)